# Installing candy icon theme on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, icon-themes

Hi I'm an Ubuntu newbie and i was just trying to figure out how to install the candy icon theme.(https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1305251/ I followed this guide(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLq7gPFlaJU&t=61s) But in the appearances tab of settings there is no way for me to change the icon theme so i installed tweaks but the candy pack does not show up in options for icons.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a terminal and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme candy-icons
```

I followed the instructions on the [official GitHub page](https://github.com/EliverLara/candy-icons). I just wrote the command down here so you can copy and paste it.